# php/webstorm toogle auto-test is triggered without saving a file

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, mocha.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm currently using php/webstorm to edit my mocha-tests.
So far everything works fine, the tests are running successfully.

But when I use  `Toggle auto-test` phpstorm is running my tests even when I just insert a blank line into any of the files without saving it.

This problem is present in phpstorm7 and 8 EAP.
I've tried to set the working directory to only my source-folder but it didn't change anything.

I've searched google and jetbrains wiki but I haven't found anything useful.

Am I missing something?

The best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP/WebStorm saves files automatically when you edit them (see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-191), so your file IS actually saved

See also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10009#comment=27-629484

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. It seems I hat a bug in phpstorm. going to accept your answer